# Guessing game by asking questions: efficiency

Tags: if-statement, binary-tree, performance

I am tackling one of the exercises in Stroustrup's book whereby I have to design a program to guess a number between 1-100 that the user is thinking of by asking questions i.e. "Is it less than 50?" etc. I can't ask more than 7 questions to get to the answer.

So far I have something like this:

```
string answer;

cout << "Think of a number between 1 and 100.\n";

cout << "Is it even or odd? (E/O)\n";

cin >> answer;

if (answer == "E") 
{
    cout << "Is it less than 50? (Y/N)\n";
    cin >> answer; 
    if (answer == "Y")
    {
        cout << "Is it less than 25? (Y/N)\n";
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer == "Y")
        {
            cout << "Is it less than 15? (Y/N)\n";
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == "Y")
            {
                cout << "Is it less than 9? (Y/N)\n";
                cin >> answer;
                if (answer == "Y")
                {
                    cout << "Is it less than 5? (Y/N)\n";
                    cin >> answer;
                    if (answer == "Y")
                    {
                        cout << "Is it less than 3? (Y/N)\n";
                        cin >> answer;
                        if (answer == "Y") 
                        {
                            cout << "Your number is 2.";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

I feel this is really bad because I have only one path of the flow diagram and already this program is quite long. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I pick 99.....the program ends.

Comment: Like I said I haven't completed it...it's only 1 path of the tree

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to either remove half or add half to the number you guessed before, based on what the user said. If you ask for input in a loop, you can simply add or remove half of the number each time, asking the new number.

So basically, instead of hard coding each question, you just ask the same question every time but using the last number / 2 or + (/2) in a loop.

I assume you don't really want us to write the code for you, so I wont. I'm sure you can figure it out with that clue! Check out for/while loops, as you need those to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you clarify what you mean by remove half/add half? Are you referring to questioning the user by solely asking "Is it less than --" sort of questions each time asking halfway between what was previously asked?